# Google Translate API Authentication

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-translation-api

I just installed the google translate api but when I try to use it within visual studios it gives me this error; `

> System.InvalidOperationException
>     HResult=0x80131509
>     Message=The Application Default Credentials are not available.

They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information. 
I've had a look around and I can't seem to make sense of it. Would anyone be able to tell me how to solve it please, thank you.

Comment: PLease edit your question and include your code.  We need to see how your application is loading GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and where it is using the value it has loaded

Comment: Please update your question with more details - otherwise it's hard to guess what's the issue.

Comment: Sorry I dont have access to the code right at this moment however I will upload it later on tonight

Comment: Imports Google.Cloud.Translation.V2
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TranslateText(InputText)
        Dim Client = TranslationClient.Create()
        Dim InText = InputText
        Dim response = Client.TranslateText(InText, LanguageCodes.Japanese, LanguageCodes.English)
        MessageBox.Show(response.TranslatedText)
    End Sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with this library or API, but I looked at the documentation you linked to. It looks like the library is looking for a some sort of JSON text file containing the credentials.

I'm going to assume you have that, cause I don't know enough to tell you how to get/create it. I'll also assume you're not running "on Compute Engine, GKE, the App Engine flexible environment, or Cloud Functions".

In this senario, the library is going to look for an environment variable called `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (as you know), which it assumes will contain the path of the JSON file. So all you have to do is set that environment variable before calling any of the methods from this library.

You can use [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable) for this. Just call it when your application starts up:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", PathToJSONFile)
```